# How to increase height of empty list in html

Tags: html

I have a form on my html page, with a text box and `<span id="list">`. When anything is searched in the text box, the results appear in the list via javacript. However the default size of empty list remains too small and doesn't appeal aesthetically. How can I set the default height of list box to say minimum 7 lines?

```js
   function promptAdd(list) {
     var text = "";
     var inputs = document.querySelectorAll("input[type=text]");
   
     for (var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
       text += inputs[i].value;
     }
   
     var lis = document.querySelectorAll('#list li');
     for (var i = 0; i < lis.length; i++) {
       if (lis[i].innerText == text ){
         resetInputs();
   
         return false;
       }
     }
   
     var li = document.createElement("li");
     var node = document.createTextNode(text);
   
     li.appendChild(node);
     document.getElementById("list").appendChild(li);
   
     resetInputs();
   }
   
   function resetInputs(){
     var inputs = document.querySelectorAll("input[type=text]");
   
     for (var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
       inputs[i].value = "";
     }
   }
```

```html
<div class="row">
<div class="col-lg-6 mb-1">
<div class="card h-100 text-left">
<div class="card-body">
<h4 class="card-title">Add Resources</h4>
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="employee" placeholder="Enter Name" />
<small id="message" class="form-text text-muted">Press + to add to your list</small>
<button id="bd1" class="btn add-more" onclick="promptAdd(list)" type="button">+</button>
<br></br>
<h5>List of Resources added</h5>
<div class="form-control" id="list">
   <span id="list">
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think the below answer will work if there aren't any items.  But the answer is on the right track.  for your span add the following css:

```
display:block;
min-height:30px;
```

or you can just set the div above the span with:

```
min-height:30px;
```